# Format Word 2016 table cell

Tags: vba, ms-word, formatting, cell, selection

Developing a planning tool in Word, I use a table for each session of a training course. I want to format individual cells according to their column (two color options for each). For layout purposes, some title row cells are merged. I want my user to right-click on cells below the "P"-title, then select the activity type which is then color-coded as cell background shading.

[image: Image: Training session table, cells under P only color-coded, no text]

Hence my `Range` object returns runtime error 5992 like "As table has different number of columns, this collection does not offer access to individual columns"

```
Sub Makro2()
  Dim minCelle As Range
  Selection.SelectCell
  Set minCelle = Selection.Range
  minCelle.Text = minCelle.Columns.First.Index
  ' Here the error occurs. As a starting point, I want VBA to insert col#
End Sub
```

Once I have established column numbers, I can work on with conditional coloring.

I work in Word 2016, but would like, if possible some backward compatibility. I tried it out on a MWE: a Word 2016 `.docm` document containing a two-row, three-col table with two cells merged in the first row, and containing a macro with the code above.

Comment: I'm a bit confused: Do you need to format individual cells (your explanation gives me that impression) or entire columns? In a quick test, the following returns the right column for me, even if cells are merged in the first row: Selection.Cells(1).ColumnIndex

Comment: Can't check right now, but I will in the morning. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing the correction from @CindyMeister below, I get the actual column number.

```
Sub Makro2()
  Dim minCelle As Range
  Selection.SelectCell
  Set minCelle = Selection.Range
  minCelle.Text = Selection.Cells(1).ColumnIndex
End Sub
```